# How do I access a label inside a <td> in a repeater in another <td> in the same repeater?

Tags: c#, html

I need to access a label text to another  in the repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("strRoles") %>'></asp:Label><%--<%# Eval("strRoles")%>--%></td>
            <td><%if ( Label1.Text == "Creator") {%>
                <a href="#modal-danger" data-toggle="modal" 
                    onclick='<%# Eval("intProjectId", "saveID(\"{0}\")")%>' 
                    title="Delete">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size: 24px; color: #9c9798;"></i>
                </a>
            <%} %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But i cannot access the id Label1 in the if loop. can anyone help me please

Comment: You have an unessessary div closing tag! Can you explain what you are trying to do? It would be easier to resolve in code behind if that is an option for you.

Comment: i need to access the label inside the if loop

Comment: **IF LOOP**?? Please study what is loop and condition.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in code behind:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("strRoles") %>'></asp:Label></td>
      <td>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="Hyp1" runat="server" href="#modal-danger" data-toggle="modal" title="Delete" Visible="False">
          <i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size: 24px; color: #9c9798;"></i>
        </asp:HyperLink>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    Label Label1 = e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
    HyperLink Hyp1 = e.Item.FindControl("Hyp1");
    int intProjectId = e.Item.DataItem("intProjectId");

    if ((Label1.Text == "Creator")) {
        Hyp1.Visible = true;
        Hyp1.Attributes.Add("onclick", ("saveID(" + intProjectId + ")"));
    }

}
```